# Disable shipping methods having a specific word and based on a shipping class in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I've used a [Business Bloomer snippet](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-free-shipping-if-cart-has-shipping-class) and tweaked it a bit to unset some shipping methods depending on a shipping class of items in the cart.

It works fine with the 4 shipping methods I have tested with but in order to fully work on my website, I have to list all shipping methods values manually and I have A LOT ( 86 to unset in `if` and 60 in `else`.)

Therefore, I would like to edit the snipped so I could unset all shipping methods that contains the same term all at once rather than look for each value individually, but don't really know how to.

I have prints for sale and so I’ve set some shipping methods for orders including prints and some for orders whitout. Therefore all my shipping methods for prints have a value ending with “_print” when the others have a value ending with “_classique”, as you can see in the code bellow.

My goal is to disable all shipping methods ending with “_classique” when a product with the “print” shipping class in the cart and vice versa.

So far my code looks like this :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'businessbloomer_hide_regular_shipping_method', 10, 2 );

function businessbloomer_hide_regular_shipping_method( $rates, $package ) {
    $shipping_class_target = 35; // shipping class ID
    $in_cart = false;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents() as $key => $values ) {
        if( $values[ 'data' ]->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_target ) {
        $in_cart = true;
        break;
        }
    }
    if( $in_cart ) { // shipping method with value
        unset( $rates['wbs:2:d6f790a0_colissimo_sans_signature_classique'] ); 
        unset( $rates['wbs:2:d748dcd4_lettre_suivie_classique'] ); 
        unset( $rates['wbs:2:f1058bc8_colissimo_avec_signature_classique'] ); 

    }
    else{
        unset( $rates['wbs:2:1cdf4913_colissimo_sans_signature_print'] );
        unset( $rates['wbs:2:fghla482_lettre_suivie_print'] );
        unset( $rates['wbs:2:g27a1f56_colissimo_avec_signature_print'] );


    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Any help on how to achieve this would be very appreciated.
Thank you to anyone who'll take time to read this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Using PHP `strpos()` will allow you to check if a word is contained in a string. Then you will need to make some changes in your code to make it work:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'show_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function show_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    $shipping_class_id = 35; // Targeted shipping class ID
    $found = false;
    
    // Loop through cart items for the current package
    foreach ( $package['contents'] as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $shipping_class_id ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        if ( $found && strpos($rate_key, '_classique') !== false ) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]); 
        } 
        elseif (! $found && strpos($rate_key, '_print') !== false ) {
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> **Clearing shipping caches**:
>
> - You will need to empty your cart, to clear cached shipping data
> - Or In shipping settings, you can disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save.

Related:

- [How can I check if a word is contained in another string using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019169/how-can-i-check-if-a-word-is-contained-in-another-string-using-php)
- [Hide shipping methods for specific shipping class in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718180/hide-shipping-methods-for-specific-shipping-class-in-woocommerce/47732732#47732732)
- [Filter Shipping method based on shipping class in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49847171/filter-shipping-method-based-on-shipping-class-in-woocommerce-3/49847815#49847815)

Comment: Oops, I deleted my comment thinking I posted it without noticing your code update but maybe you did update it after I posted the comment. Anyway thanks a LOT it works like a charm. Have a wonderful day !